# Palstar algorithm Dynamic Programming getting the result

Tags: algorithms, optimization, dynamic-programming

I recently started to read abour dynamic programming, and I am doing an exercise on it.
The problem to solve: 
Given a String, find the least amount of palindromes it can be split into, and
print out the solution.
I found this article on here: 
[Is there an algorithm for checking if a string is a catenation of palindromes?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9540/is-there-an-algorithm-for-checking-if-a-string-is-a-catenation-of-palindromes)

It helps me, but I dont quite get the last step of the answer: Quote:

> Now, you can compute `s[1,…,j+1]`, by checking for each $1\le i\le j−1$ whether `s[1,…,i]` can be decomposed, and if `s[i+1,…,j+1]` is a palindrome (using the above 2D table). Giving a $\Theta(n^2)$ time and $\Theta(n^2)$ space algorithm.

What do I do here? I am confused.

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know dynamic programming?  What specifically are you confused about?  Have you tried working through a small example to try to fill in the blanks?  Have you tried re-reading a textbook chapter on dynamic programming and doing some practice dynamic programming problems from a textbook, to refresh your memory?  Did you try posting a comment on that answer?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: There was some confusion in the answer you linked, which DW edited (thanks!). Please re-read and see if that makes sense now.

btw, that question deals with "whether a string is a concatenation of non-trivial palindromes", while you want a decomposition into the minimum numbers, possibly including the trivial decomposition (each character is a palindrome in itself).

The dynamic programming algorithm in that answer can be modified to maintain the actual number of palindromes in the minimal decomposition of $s[1 \dots j]$ (instead of a boolean Yes/No as in that answer).